# How to select a calendar week in SAPUI5?

Tags: datepicker, sapui5

I am searching for a way to select just a calendar week with a `DatePicker`.
Is there a way to configure that control in a way, that it allows to pick a week and sends a `DateTime` element out of this week?

I detected the following entry with a list of format options, but week formatting seems not working:
http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/04/28/working-with-odata-dates

This code seems not working:

```
new sap.m.DatePicker({
  value : {
    path : "DateTime",
    type : new sap.ui.model.type.Date({pattern: "w yy"})
  }
}),
```

The binding is to OData property `DateTime` of type `Edm:DateTime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Few things to be noticed:**

Though **SAPUI5** says it supports weeks in year, it **doesn't** currently! //I tested

why? in DateFormat.js file of SAPUI5

```
case "weekInYear":
    sWeek = "";
    //TODO getWeek does not exist on Date object
    //-> this is a preparation for a future or custom week support
    if (oDate.getWeek) {
        sWeek += oDate.getWeek();
    }
    aBuffer.push(jQuery.sap.padLeft(sWeek, "0", oPart.iDigits));
    break;
```

As you can see, its in **TODO** list!!

**Workaround? Yes :**

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat");

//define getWeek function
Date.prototype.getWeek = function () {
    var d = new Date(+this);
    d.setHours(0, 0, 0);
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - (d.getDay() || 7));
    return Math.ceil((((d - new Date(d.getFullYear(), 0, 1)) / 8.64e7) + 1) / 7);
};
var oDateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({
    pattern: "w y"
});
var oDatePicker = new sap.m.DatePicker({
    dateValue: new Date(),
    displayFormat: "w y"
})
```

[JSBin code piece is here](http://jsbin.com/biraxisaxa/3/edit?html,output)